# Faster image paint method

Tags: c#, winforms

My project consists of a video player and a image viewer, both fullscreen in a panel with only one visible at a time. When the video pauses I capture the frame, display it in the image viewer and swap which control is visible. The problem is, when the image viewer is shown you see the previous image for a brief second before the new image is painted.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can prevent this? Ideally I want it to be seemless when the controls swap.

I've already set the image viewer to be double buffered.

Edit:
Code, doesn't really show much here.

```
private void ShowImageView()
{
    this.axWindowsMediaPlayer.Visible = false;
    this.imageViewer.Visible = true;
}

private void ShowVideoView()
{
    this.axWindowsMediaPlayer.Visible = true;
    this.imageViewer.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Show some code... what if you switch visibility only after new image is loaded? also check double buffering... it may help

Comment: Code doesn't really show much here (added it anyway), just a call to hide the video player followed by a call to show the image viewer. I've already made the control double buffered, it made a bit of an improvement.

Comment: How do you measure the "delay"? Between ShowImageView() is run and you actually see the imageViewer? Are your image and preloaded? ( Loaded before shown )  Post your code snippet for "capturing and displaying it".

Comment: ShowVideoView works just how I want it to. The video is loaded at the beginning, takes a few seconds, but that's fine, it's instant after that. The issue is with ShowImageView, the image viewer showing the previous image for a second, so it looks like it jumps.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it, the image viewer had a Image Changed event that I hadn't spotted (I'd tried using the Image Loaded event). Subscribing to the image changed event and only showing the control then, seems to give me the transistion I was looking for.